# Add message/warning while printing the documents in SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, printing

Is there any feature in O365/SharePoint document management policy to add messages/warnings while printing the documents? something like on print trigger or so?

The requirement is to display the expiry date on print from the metadata therein document library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, print feature is based on office products such as word, excel,PowerPoint and so on, and has little to do with SharePoint.

So there is no related SharePoint solution to add a message when printing a document.